# Symfony2 sonata new project

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I want to create a new Web Symfony2 project. I want to use some sonata components (media, commerce, admin, cms, ...)

I have read sonata project documentation and i have found this:

I must run "composer create-project sonata-project/sandbox:2.3.x-dev"

I just want to create an empty projects with sonata components and then develop by myself.

Is this command correct ? Or does it just give an example ?

I want stable version of components.

Comment: It's quite time consuming to find all the version which work together.. On GitHub you can find all kinds of 'empty projects'. E.g.: https://github.com/jmather/symfony-sonata-distribution it can help you get started.